# Does multi-threaded code increase real-time memory usage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Recently, I'm learning about multithreading. There is some confusion about the memory usage of multiple threads. Does multi-threaded code increase real-time memory usage? I wrote the following two pieces of code.
First, single-thread implementation of code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    A* pA = new A;
    pA->dosomething();
    delete pA;
}
```

First, multi-thread implementation of code is as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        A* pA = new A;
        pA->dosomething();
        delete pA;
    }
```

Is it possible that the multi-thread code occupies 1000 A-size memory at a certain time?But single-threaded program occupies a maximum of one A memory at a certain time.
I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.
Can someone help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: The parallel version (if it ends up using more than 1 thread) will have more `A` instances created at one time. With the serial version only 1 will exist at a time.

Comment: ***Is it possible that the multi-thread code occupies 1000 A-size memory at a certain time?*** If you had 1000 threads I would expect this to happen.

Comment: And if you didn't have 1000 cores, it could still happen.  Those 1000 iterations of the loop are permitted to run in parallel.

Comment: You have to be more clear and specific. Are you asking for a mechanism of the thread or the implementation of OpenMP? Anyway, experiment yourself varying the ```OMP_NUM_THREADS``` environment variable.

Comment: It's not difficult to experiment by yourself. You have already a piece of code, I don't know what the pA object is, but try allocating (and initializing) a large object (such an array with hundreds million elements) and monitor the memory usage of your process.

Comment: Note that the parallel runtime also needs memory, so a parallel code not allocating memory at all occupies more memory than the serial one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the code for single thread and multiread. And the result shows the multi-threaded code increase real-time memory usage. And the amount of memory added depends on how much memory is being consumed simultaneously in multiple threads.

For example, single-thread implementation of code is as follows:

```
#include <omp.h>      // OpenMP
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void* create(unsigned int size)
{
    void *m = malloc(size);
    memset(m,0,size);
    return m;
}
void create_destory(unsigned int size)
{
    void* p = create(size);
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int mega = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        create_destory(mega);
    }
}
```

The compilation options are as follows:

```
g++ test_memory_single_thread.cc -fopenmp -std=c++11 -o test_memory_single_thread
```

Then use /usr/bin/time -v to test the peak memory usage of a process

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./test_memory_single_thread
```

The result shows the Maximum resident set size(kbytes) is 1049928
I tested it many times. The Maximum resident set size(kbytes) is always about 1049928

Secondly, multi-thread implementation of code is as follows:

```
#include <omp.h>      // OpenMP
#include <memory.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void* create(unsigned int size)
{
    void *m = malloc(size);
    memset(m,0,size);
    return m;
}
void create_destory(unsigned int size)
{
    void* p = create(size);
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int mega = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        create_destory(mega);
    }
}
```

The compilation options are as follows:

```
g++ test_memory_multi_thread.cc -fopenmp -std=c++11 -o test_memory_multi_thread
```

Then use /usr/bin/time -v to test the peak memory usage of a process

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./test_memory_multi_thread
```

The result shows the Maximum resident set size(kbytes) is 3037564

I tested it many times. The Maximum resident set size(kbytes) may be 3627164, 2925496 and so on

Therefore, the result shows the multi-threaded code increase more real-time memory usage.

Comment: You are allocating some 1GB arrays, aren't you puzzled to measure only 8MB at most?

Comment: @PierU Thanks a lot for your advice. The original code I used malloc to allocate 1 gigabyte of memory, but did not fill the memory, so the test results were problematic. I updated the code and test results, please check out.

Comment: This is the difference between "virtual memory" and "resident memory". When you allocate an object it is counted in the "virtual memory" but not in the "resident memory" because no memory page is attributed at this point. It's only when you access the object (i.e. writing something in) that it "physically" exists in memory and that it appears in the "resident memory"